# Unable to reset cookie

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, timer, laravel-4

In my application, I'm using time counter in fronend using js. I want to reset timer cookie when timer expires.

Setting timer in cookie

```
setcookie("timer_user_".$customer['entity_id']."_product_".$id, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+2 min')));
```

Deleting timer in cookie

```
setcookie("timer_user_".$customer['entity_id']."_product_".$id, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-2 min')));
```

Logging this cooke value immediately.I'm getting value

Comment: use `unset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);`

Comment: Log::info("timer_user_".$customer['entity_id']."_product_".$id);
Log::info("value".$_COOKIE["timer_user_".$customer['entity_id']."_product_".$id]);
//immediately after unset($_COOKIE["timer_user_".$customer['entity_id']."_product_".$id]);
[2018-06-11 10:06:56] local.INFO: timer_user_16396_product_40936 [] []
[2018-06-11 10:06:56] local.INFO: value [] []
//but later in another function
[2018-06-11 10:07:27] local.INFO: timer_user_16396_product_40936 [] []
[2018-06-11 10:07:27] local.INFO: value 2018-06-11 10:06:51 [] [] why Im getting cookie value later but not in immediate log @TarangP